# Batch Normalization: Axis on which to take mean and variance

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement Batch Normalization (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf) in my convolutional neural network, but I am really confused as around what axis I should calculate mean and variance.

If an input to the conv-layer is of shape 3 * 224 * 224 * 32
where:
3- input channels.
224 * 224- shape of single channel
32- minibatch size

**What should be the axis in the following formula**
Mean = numpy.mean(input_layer, axis= ? )

And, if an input to the fully connected layer is of shape 100 * 32
where:
100- number of inputs
32- minibatch size

Again, **what should be the axis in the following formula**
Mean = numpy.mean(input_layer, axis= ? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# 1. axis = (1,2,3)
numpy.mean(input_layer,axis=(1,2,3)) 
# 2. axis = 1
numpy.mean(input_layer,axis=1)
```

For convolutional layers with shared weights it uses feature-wise normalization, for fully connected layers it uses sample-wise normalization.

Code of the BN layer of the Keras library for reference: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/0daec53acbf4c3df6c054b36ece5c1ae2db55d86/keras/layers/normalization.py

Comment: Hi dontloo, thanks for your reply. But in the BN paper under section 3.2 (Batach Normalization Convolutoinal Networks), it is mentioned : "we use the effective mini-batch of size m′ = |B| = m · pq" where p x q is the is the size of feature map. So does it not imply that axis for convolution layer and fully connected layer should be different?

Comment: @Amrit yes you're right, very sorry about my nonsense answer. I'll update it a bit and link some code for reference.

Comment: Thank's it seems correct to me. Just to mention: I guess we could also use "numpy.mean(input_layer, axis= (1,2,3) )" for conv layer which is more compact form of your answer.

Comment: @Amrit yep you're right again, it's like you've answered your own question, and I'm just here to write it down for you, lol